# Vue component does not react to plugin data changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, watch

I'm trying to make a component react to data changes in a Vue plugin. To do so, when the plugin is instantiated, it instantiates a Vue object in its constructor like this:

```
this._vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    obj: null,
    status: false,
  },
  watch: {
    obj(val) {
      console.log('From inside the plugin, "obj" changed:', val);
    }
  }
})
```

On page load, the application checks if `localStorage` contains data for the `obj` property. If this is the case, after the Vue instance is created as shown above, an object is assigned to the property like this: `this._vm.obj = {x: 1, y:2, z:3}`. This works well, I see the following in my console:

```
15:55:37.346 Component mounted, "obj": Object { … }
15:55:37.350 From inside the plugin, "obj" changed: Object { … }
```

I can even programmatically reset `this._vm.obj` to `null`, upon which the console displays the reactivity as expected:

```
16:11:48.722 From inside the plugin, "obj" changed: null
16:11:48.726 Component watch "status": false
16:11:48.727 Component watch "obj": null
```

However, if no data is found in `localStorage`, a request is made to the server and the response data is used to update `this._vm.obj`. The method used to do so is the same as above (which does `this._vm.obj = {x: 1, y:2, z:3}`). The watcher in the plugin reacts (`From inside the plugin, "obj" changed`), but not the component...

If anyone has a pointer, that would be great!

**Some snippets**:
The watchers in the component:

```
watch: {
  '$MyPlugin.status'(val) {
    console.log('Component watch "status":', val)
  },
  '$MyPlugin.obj'(val) {
    console.log('Component watch "obj":', val)
  }
},
```

The plugin class has getters to access the data:

```
get status() {
  return this._vm.status || false
}

get obj() {
  return this._vm.obj
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. The problem was simply that in some cases my plugin class returned a void promise from its constructor — something I did not expect to have any effect. (Turns out [constructors can return something](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).)

Below is my plugin's `install` function. When `instance` was a void promise, instead of a MyPlugin object, the properties I tried to watch from other components were initially `undefined` and thus not reactive.

```
export default (() => {

    return function install(Vue, options) {

        let instance = new MyPlugin(Vue, options);

        Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
            $MyPlugin: {
                get: function () {
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```